# Qt Swipeview with Flickable not scrolling

Tags: qt, qml

I have a Qt/QML file with a SwipeView. I want each page of the SwipeView to be scrollable when the screen width and height change and also when the native keyboard pops up. I have 3 problems with the Components in the code below.

```
ApplicationWindow {
id: appWindow
SwipeView {
        anchors.top: appWindow.top
        anchors.bottom: tabBar.top
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.left: parent.left
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

Flickable {
            id: page1
            //            contentWidth: parent.width
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
            Component1 {
                id: screen01
            }
        }


Flickable {
            id: page2
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
            Component2 {
                id: screen02
            }
        }
   }//SwipeView


footer: TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        contentHeight: appWindow.height/10
        width: appWindow.width
        currentIndex: parent.currentIndex
        anchors.top: appWindow.top
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        TabButton {
            id: tabPage1
            width: appWindow.width/2
            text: qsTr("Page1")
        }

        TabButton {
            id: tabPage2
            width: appWindow.width/2
            text: qsTr("Page2")
            }
        }
    }//footer

}//appwindow



--- Component1 --- 
Rectangle {
 id: rectangle 
Image {
 id: backgroundImage 
 anchors.fill:parent
source: "myimage.jpg"
}

GridLayout {
id: gridLayout
rows:2 
anchors.fill: parent

Text {
 Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.preferredWidth: 0.8 * parent.width
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
                color: "black"
                text: qsTr("Page1")
                font.pixelSize: 34
                font.bold: true
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
}
TextField { 
                id: textField
                color: "black"
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.preferredWidth: 80
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter | Text.AlignJustify
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignJustify
                text: qsTr("Enter")
}

}//GridLayout

}//Component1
```

Pblm 1: I want the Component to be Scrollable and in the Center of the page
Component 1 and Component 2 have a background image with a Gridlayout. I'm not able to get the GridLayout to be in the center of the page and apply scrollable. When I get scrollable to work, the gridLayout goes to the left of the page.

Pblm 2: I want to have an image in the bakground of a scrollable page.
When I add an image in the background of Component1 or Component2 (rectangles with background image + GridLayout), Scroll is disabled. When I remove the background image, I can use the Scroll.

Pblm 3: I want the GridLayout view to become scrollable when the native keyboard pops-up when I click on a Text Input.
I have text inputs in the GridLayout, but when the native keyboard pops up, it doesn't scroll the view of the Components.

Can I have an example to make Component1 and Component2 work without these 3 issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code, and they come down to an understanding of `width` and `height` and `anchoring`. Whilst debugging, I highly recommend you verify the `width` and `height` of your components by using debugging techniques like `console.log`.

The first set of fixes can be done by sizing the `Flickable` and the `Component` relative to the `SwipeView`, e.g.

```
    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex
        Flickable {
            id: page1
            width: swipeView.width
            height: swipeView.height
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
            Component1 {
                id: screen01
                width: page1.width
                height: page1.height
            }
        }
        //...
```

The next set of fixes is relate to `SwipeView`'s height. There is an issue because `anchors.bottom: tapBar.top` will not work since `TapBar` is placed in the `footer` region. In fact, because the `TabBar` is there, it is okay to set `anchors.fill: parent` for your `SwipeView`.

I've tidied up your application so that it runs:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick3D
Page {
    id: appWindow
    SwipeView {
id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex
        
        Flickable {
            id: page1
width: swipeView.width
height: swipeView.height
            //            contentWidth: parent.width
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
            Component1 {
                id: screen01
width: page1.width
height: page1.height
            }
        }
        
        
        Flickable {
            id: page2
width: swipeView.width
height: swipeView.height
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
            Component2 {
                id: screen02
width: page2.width
height: page2.height
            }
        }
    }//SwipeView
    
    
    footer: TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        contentHeight: appWindow.height/10
        width: appWindow.width
        currentIndex: parent.currentIndex
        anchors.top: appWindow.top
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        TabButton {
            id: tabPage1
            width: appWindow.width/2
            text: qsTr("Page1")
        }
        
        TabButton {
            id: tabPage2
            width: appWindow.width/2
            text: qsTr("Page2")
        }
    }//footer
    
}//appwindow



// Component1.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Rectangle {
    id: rectangle 
    Image {
        id: backgroundImage 
        anchors.fill:parent
        source: "myimage.jpg"
    }
    
    GridLayout {
        id: gridLayout
        rows:2 
        anchors.fill: parent
        
        Text {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 0.8 * parent.width
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
            color: "black"
            text: qsTr("Page1")
            font.pixelSize: 34
            font.bold: true
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        }
        TextField { 
            id: textField
            color: "black"
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 80
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter | Text.AlignJustify
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignJustify
            text: qsTr("Enter")
        }
        
    }//GridLayout
    
}//Component1

// Component2.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Rectangle {
    id: rectangle 
    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "red"
        width: 100
        height: 100
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

However, there is still the underlying issue of your `Flickable` not having a scrollbar. To fix that, you need to set `contentWidth` and `contentHeight`. The `Component1`'s `width` can inherit from the `Flickable` and the `SwipeView`. However, I do not know the correct value of `height`. A correct `height` is needed, else the `Flickable` will have a correct `contentHeight` and will have no idea how to create a scrollbar for you.

```
    Flickable {
        width: swipeView.width
        height: swipeView.height
        contentWidth: screen01.width
        contentHeight: screen01.height
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { }
        Component1 {
            id: screen01
            width: page1.width
            //height: page1.height // needs to change to something else
        }
    }
```